# how can i fix this: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, string-matching

```
fasttext_embeddings = WordEmbeddings('en-crawl')
fasttext = Embeddings(fasttext_embeddings, min_similarity=0, model_id="FastText")
tfidf = TFIDF(min_similarity=0, model_id="TF-IDF")
rapidfuzz = RapidFuzz(n_jobs=-1, score_cutoff=0, model_id="RapidFuzz")

matchers = [tfidf, fasttext, rapidfuzz]

model = PolyFuzz(matchers)

model.match(Netflix['title'], IMBD['Title'])
```

i used polyfuzz to do fuzzy string matching and get this error, how can i fix this error? thanks
[image]

Comment: Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message. Also, [please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to *understand* the error message by researching it first. By reading the error message, you should be able to understand *where* in your code it comes from, and start looking for a cause. Also, keep in mind that we can only help with problems that we can actually see. I have no idea what `WordEmbeddings`, `Embeddings`, `TFIDF` etc. do, because there are no definitions here. Please read [mre].

Comment: You are missing the `imports` and the `traceback`.  But one way or other the code is trying to do some sort of test on a pandas `Sereies` (dataframe column).  The test requires a simple True/False, but a Series test, like a `numpy` array, is doing an elementwise test, resulting in multiple True/False values.  Is the fuzzy logic code compatible with `numpy` or `pandas`?  Did you reread the docs with that in mind?

Answer (score 0):

I would have preferred a copy-n-paste of the traceback, but the image is readable (barely).  The error occurs in a line

```
 if to_list:
```

and earlier we we the default value fo `to_list` is `None`.  This `if` is trying skip the case where `to_list` is `None`, or an empty list.  Tracing further back I see that `to_list` is the second argument in the `match` call:

```
model.match(Netflix['title'], IMBD['Title'])
```

In your case that's a pandas Series.  `if IMBD['Title']`: would produce this error.

Double check the docs, but it looks like this imported module expects lists as arguments.  If may work if you first convert the Series to lists.

Read the function docs, preferably before you use it, but even more so when you get errors.  That, and traceback, are keys to debugging.